# How to fix field doesn't exist error on Odoo

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, odoo

I found a module in Odoo apps that would help a lot, but it was for version 6.1, so i decided to update it for V13.0, i went through all python's problems i think but now i get some XML related errors when i try to install the app....

```
Odoo Server Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "d:\Program Files\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_ui_view.py", line 394, in _check_xml
self.postprocess_and_fields(view.model, view_doc, view.id)
File "d:\Program Files\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_ui_view.py", line 994, 
in postprocess_and_fields
self.raise_view_error(message, view_id)
File "d:\Program Files\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_ui_view.py", line 614, 
in raise_view_error
raise ValueError(message)
ValueError: Field `partner_id` does not exist
```

But it's created in the model :

```
class generate_purchase_order(models.TransientModel):
_name = 'sale_to_purchase_order.generate_purchase_order'
_description = 'Generate Purchase Order'

_columns = {
    'partner_id': fields.Many2one('res.partner', 'Supplier', required=True, domain="[('supplier','=',True)]"),
    'pricelist_id': fields.Many2one('product.pricelist', 'Purchase Pricelist', required=True, domain="[('type','=','purchase')]",
                    help="This pricelist will be used, instead of the default one, for purchases from the current partner",),
    'warehouse_id': fields.Many2one('stock.warehouse', 'Warehouse', required=True,),
}
```

Here's the view :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
```

```
<record id="view_generate_purchase_order_wizard" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">Generate Purchase Order</field>
        <field name="model">sale_to_purchase_order.generate_purchase_order</field>
        <field name="type">form</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="Generate Purchase Order">
                <group col="4" colspan="4">
                    <label colspan="4" width="500"
                           string="You are on about to generate a Purchase Order from this Sale Order. To do so please complete the following mandatory fields first."/>
                    <newline/>
                    
                    <field name="partner_id" colspan="4" on_change="onchange_partner_id(partner_id)"
                           context="{'search_default_supplier': True, 'default_supplier': True, 'default_customer': False}"/>
                    
                    <field name="pricelist_id" colspan="4"/>
                    
                    <field name="warehouse_id" colspan="4"/>
                    
                    <button string="Cancel" colspan="2" special="cancel" icon="gtk-cancel" />
                    <button name="generate_purchase_order" string="Generate Purchase Order"
                            icon="gtk-go-forward" type="object" colspan="2"/>
                </group>
            </form>
        </field>
</record>
```

Comment: Sorry, but i downvoted because the last time i've looked into the question there wasn't enough information to help yout. Because without knowing what model (definition) and view (definition) we could only tell you, that a field definition is missing.

Comment: So after you've added more info: why do you use `_columns` in your model definition? I'm  astonished that it is working whatsoever, because you just define/declare class attributes for fields since Odoo 8 (new API). Probably that's why the field seems to be missing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the fact is i'm rewriting an old module so i kept variables as it was, i'm new to Odoo, so i don't know much about the changes between versions ! How should i declare my fields ?

Comment: You will find enough information in Odoo's documentation and tutorials. In this one case it should be a class attribute which should look like `partner_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name='res.partner', string='Supplier', required=True, domain="[('supplier','=',True)]")`. But the domain shouldn't work anymore in Odoo 13 so just don't declare it.